# Backbone js code smell - better way to embed a sub-view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-relational

I'm building a backbone app using backbone-relational models (but that shouldn't matter for this question).

Basically, I have an edit button that will display a hidden div. Inside the hidden div id a sub-view (called `DetailsView`) that renders table elements to populate a list of users. My model (for the whole app) looks roughly like this:

```
{ 'id': 'foo',
  'users': 
   {
   'username': 'bobby',
   'password': 'peanuts'
   },
   {
   'username': 'sally',
   'password': 'watermellon'
   }
}
```

In my main view (that is fed by a collection of the above models), when the user clicks the edit button, this is triggered:

```
edit: function(){
      var userModels = this.model.get('users'),
          detailViewContainer = this.$('tbody.users');
      console.log(name + ' has ' + userModels.length + ' models');
      //clear out eveything in tbody.users to prevent dupes
      detailViewContainer.html('');
      //check if there are actually user models
      if(userModels.length > 0){
        userModels.forEach(function(user) {
         var details = new DetailsView({model: user});
         details.render();
         detailViewContainer.append(details.el);
         });
}
```

The code smell comes from the fact that I have to declare that `detailViewContainer` explicitly.

Originally, in my forEach loop would call another function in the view that contained the code to declare and render the `DetailsView`. However, I would loose the context of `this`.

My original code looked something like this:

```
   edit: function() {
      var userModels = this.model.get('users'),
          detailViewContainer = this.$('tbody.users');
      console.log(name + ' has ' + userModels.length + ' models');
      //clear out eveything in tbody.users to prevent dupes
      detailViewContainer.html('');
      //check if there are actually user models
      if(userModels.length > 0){
        userModels.forEach(function(user) {
         this.renderDetailsView;
         });
      }
    },

    renderDetailsView: function(user) {
       var details = new DetailsView({model: user});
       this.$('tbody.users').append(details.render());
     },
```

In the `renderDetailsView`, I would loose context of `this` and could not append the `DetailsView` to the proper DOM element (the view would append to all of the `tbody.users` DOM elements , as the `this` context became the window since it was in a loop).

Having to explicitly declare a `detailsViewContainer` seems hacky to me, and I'd like to be able to keep the `this` context pointing to the main view, not the entire window.

The `DetailsView` template just a set of `<tr><td></td></tr>` elements. Is there a better way to embed this view without having to resort to creating the `detailViewContainer`?

(One possible option was having the `DetailView` loop through the collection returned from `this.model.get('users')` all by itself... is that a good idea?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing what you're doing because of the loss of 'this,' you can pass your context to forEach.

```
userModels.forEach(function(user) {
     this.renderDetailsView();
},this);
```

Now you have the proper 'this' available to you. Hope this helps.

Comment: Whoa, didn't realize you could pass in the context... mind blown

Comment: Actually, no... :) I don't normally miss stuff like that.